# Prove that $\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}x^n = n!$

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing, induction

I started this by induction and proved the base case $n = 1$ and assumed true for $n = k$ so $\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k}x^k = k!$

I then let $n = k+1$ and I started the inductive step by writing that you can differentiate $\frac{\mathrm{d}^ky}{\mathrm{d}x^k}$, so $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(
\frac{\mathrm{d}^ky}{\mathrm{d}x^k}\right)$. I then got stuck because I didn't know what I would be differentiating ($x^k$ maybe?).

I know I should end up with $(k+1)k!$ so that ends up with $(k+1)!$ but I'm not sure how to get there.

Can anyone please help me :)

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proof by induction (derivative of $x^n=n!$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197716/proof-by-induction-derivative-of-xn-n) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7D%5En%7D%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7Dx%5En%7Dx%5En%20%3D%20n!%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the induction step, suppose

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k}x^k=k!$$

for some $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. Then

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{k+1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{k+1}}x^{k+1}
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} x^{k+1}\right) \\
&=(k+1)\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k}x^k \\
&=(k+1)\cdot k! \\
&= (k+1)!.
\end{align*}

The result now follows.